# FCKEditor don't work after upload on my site

Tags: php, .htaccess, fckeditor

I use FCKEditor as an editor on my website. I create website on my local host and put editor in it and it works fine. But after uploading my website (include FCKEditor dir), editor not work! No directory and nothing of source was changed!

There is an .htacess file in FCKEditor directory. Is it the problem?

*sorry for bad Enghish!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make sure you have uploaded all the related files of fckeditor (js/css and all) and the referenced path are correct.

2) Check the folder names/filenames. I had same kind of issue when i moved files to my production server (shared hosting).in the code it was calling a file in folder "js" and my actual folder was "Js". I am talking about case sensitivity

Comment: I make zip the website directory and after upload, extracted all files in website root directory. Nothing was changed!

Comment: Did you check the case sensitivity ?

Comment: Can i have a look @ it  ? Is this hosted somewhere ?